# how to create a bootstrap card using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a card created and defined in HTML. I want to get rid of it in the HTML and therefore create the same card using jquery/javascript, that way a new one can be created on the click of a button.

```html
<div id="divEntryPanel" class ="col-sm-6" style="display:none">
   <div class="card aircat-card-border">
      <div class="card-header bg-info">
         <h5 style="font-weight: bold">Additional Entry</h5>
      </div>
      <div id="pnlEntry" class="bg-secondary">
         <div class="pt-2 form-group">
            <asp:Label CssClass="row pl-3" runat="server" Text="Intended Action: "></asp:Label> 
             <textarea style="width: 100%;" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Textarea1" runat="server" cols="50" rows="2" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
             <asp:Label CssClass="row pl-3" runat="server" Text="Intended completion date: "></asp:Label>
             <textarea style="width: 100%;" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Textarea2" runat="server" cols="50" rows="2" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
             <asp:Label CssClass="row pl-3" runat="server" Text="extra details: ">
               <asp:Label CssClass="text-dark small" runat="server" Text="(200 Character Limit )"></asp:Label>
             </asp:Label>
             <textarea style="width: 100%;" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Textarea3" runat="server" cols="50" rows="2" maxlength="200"></textarea>
             <div id="EntrySaveBtn" class="col-md-12 float-right">
               <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Click to save the entry to this alert:"></asp:Label> 
               <a id="btnSaveEntry" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-2">Save</a>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.
In your HTML:

```html
<div id="divEntryPanel" class ="col-sm-6" style="display:none">
  
</div> 

<button id="myBtn">Click me</button>
```

In your javascript

```js
const card = `
  <div class="card aircat-card-border">
        <div class="card-header bg-info">
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold">Additional Entry</h5>
        </div>
    <div id="pnlEntry" class="bg-secondary">
    <div class="pt-2 form-group">

<asp:Label CssClass="row pl-3" runat="server" Text="Intended Action: "></asp:Label> 
<textarea  style="width: 100%;" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Textarea1" 
runat="server" cols="50" rows="2" maxlength="2000"></textarea>

<asp:Label CssClass="row pl-3" runat="server" Text="Intended completion date: "></asp:Label>
<textarea  style="width: 100%;" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Textarea2" 
runat="server" cols="50" rows="2" maxlength="2000"></textarea>

<asp:Label CssClass="row pl-3" runat="server" Text="extra details: ">
<asp:Label CssClass="text-dark small" runat="server" Text="(200 Character Limit )"> 
</asp:Label></asp:Label>
<textarea  style="width: 100%;" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Textarea3" 
 runat="server" cols="50" rows="2" maxlength="200"></textarea>
                                
<div id="EntrySaveBtn" class="col-md-12 float-right">
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Click to save the entry to this alert:"></asp:Label> 
    <a id="btnSaveEntry" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ml-2">Save</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
`

const button = document.getElementById("myBtn")

const mainDiv = document.getElementById("divEntryPanel")

button.onclick = function () {
 mainDiv.innerHTML += card
}
```